# unable to get template type with id:8 while publishing

Tags: publishing, razormediator

I'm Using Razor Mediator and when I publishing i'm getting unable to get template type with id:8 while publishing.

Comment: Hi Abdulla, This question is a bit light on detail and doesn't really meet our quality standards in its current form. Do you think you could update it please with more information and what you tried already to solve your issue?

Comment: +1 to Rob - Abdulla - what have you tried... can you publish anything (SGs, Components, Pages). Can you preview pages? Is this for specific pages/content types?

Comment: Nearly identical to [this SE question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13582003/395495).

Comment: any update Abdulla?

Comment: I have already installed Razor Mediator V1.2.2 in my Content Manager Server which is separated from Publisher Server. In my cms servers Publishing Services are Stopped. And I have Seperate Publishing Servers. I'm able to preview the razor mediator value which is nothing but just @Page.Title in preview mode but when I publish I got the error message : "Unable to get the Template Type with Id : 8"

Answer (score 5):

Razor seems to be registered with different id or its not installed at your CMS server, but template expecting it with Id:8

Check your `Tridion.ContentManager.config,` it should be like below:

```
 <add id="8" name="RazorTemplate" mimeType="text/x-tcm-cshtml"
hasBinaryContent="false"
 contentHandler="Tridion.Extensions.Mediators.Razor.RazorContentHandler,
 Tridion.Extensions.Mediators.Razor, Version=1.3.3.1, Culture=neutral,
 PublicKeyToken=5eeceedb34d9dfd7">
    <webDavFileExtensions>
     <add itemType="TemplateBuildingBlock" fileExtension="cshtml" />
    </webDavFileExtensions>   </add>
```

Comment: The Id is 8 in the config file.

Comment: Is razor installed(properly)? try restarting the com service if its installed.

Comment: Com+ Services, IIS and Application Pool  and even CMS Servers are also restarted

Comment: Is Razor installed on your all Publishing Servers? because while rendering on specific server razor would be required.

Comment: I have had this error before and the Razor Mediator was not installed on the server, and therefore the CMS did not recognize the 'template type' of the Razor template.  My advice would be to uninstall the Razor Mediator, restart, install the Razor Mediator, and finally restart again.  I would then test it by creating a new Razor TBB and doing as you did previously, @Page.Title in a Page Template TBB, and preview in Template Builder.

Answer (score 2):

If your Publisher is out-scaled to another server (separate to your Content Manager server), then you will also need to install, and configure, the Razor Mediator on that server too.

It is also worth noting that you have to restart the `Tridion Publisher` Windows Service after installing (or making any configuration changes to) the Razor Mediator.